# Why is DC Voltage called Direct Current ?

Tags: voltage, current, dc

I have had this question since a long time, and didn't find any other place to ask this. So thought will just ask here.

The "DC" in DC Voltage/Supplies stands for Direct Current. So why is it combined with Voltage in the name ?

From what I understand it might have something to do with a supply or voltage which has a constant current at one level. Is that the reason ?

Comment: AC Alternates Current direction. DC the current goes in one DIRECTion.

Comment: Who says "DC _voltage_ power supply?"  I've heard "DC power supply," and "<howevermany>-Volt DC supply?", and "constant voltage DC supply?" and many variations on the same; but I don't recall ever hearing the exact phrase that you are asking about.

Comment: In some languages DC is called Continuous current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Name**

With a constant load, DC (direct current) has a constant current and voltage.

This is as opposed to AC (alternating current) which, with a constant load, has an alternating current and voltage.

[image]

It's essentially a description of the current and voltage's relationship to *time*. For DC, the frequency is equal to zero, not changing in time. While AC has a frequency equal to *not* zero, it changes with time.

**Relationship between Voltage and Current**

The key to the relationship between current and voltage, is the load, or resistance. This comes from [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), \$V = IR\$. As you can see, if \$R\$, the resistance is constant then voltage (\$V\$) is equal to the current (\$I\$) times a constant coefficient. Set \$R = 1\$ and the relationship is quite obvious.

Comment: And as an adjunct, capacitances and inductances cause \$R\$ (or more correctly, \$Z\$) to be a complex number.

Answer (score 3):

"DC Voltage" and "AC Voltage" are gramatically incorrect, but everyone uses those terms.

More gramatically correct terms if we are talking about voltage would be "DV (Direct Voltage)" or "AV (Alternating Voltage)" - but no-one says that.

DC Voltage is a voltage associated with an unchanging current, while AC Voltage is the voltage associated with a current that is continually changing direction.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the direction of current which doesn't alternates but flow only in one direction in the circuit.